# UI dialog for e-mail validation not showing any dialog

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
    <html>
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //================UI dialog===========
        $(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: {
                    duration: 100
                },
                hide: {
                    duration: 100
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validation()
        {
            var emailField=document.form.email.value;
            var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
            if (reg.test(emailField.value) == false) 
            {
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        p_dialog.innerHTML="Please enter valid email ... ";         
                document.form.name.select();
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
            <p id="p_dialog"></p>
        </div>

    <form action="data.php" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return validation()" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

        <input type="text" name="email" style="width:100%" id="email">
        <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="submit" >
    </form>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here I am using UI dialog to check the validation of the e-mail field but it do not show the dialog by

```
.dialog("open")
```

Same code I used for the required field and for name field in this same form it workes good but when I apply it to e-mail it do not showing any message.

Comment: jsfiddle will help us...

Comment: Any errors in console? Why use js AND jQuery selectors? Why you specify full path to form action and not relative one? I see no jQuery loading

Comment: thanks it s done but now the poblem is it donot validate the data poperly

Comment: You have just copied the script and css from somewhere and not adjusted according to your requirement

Answer (score 1):

```
function validation()
        {   
            var emailField=document.form.email.value;
            var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
            if (filter.test(emailField)) { 
                return true; 
            }
            else {
                  document.getElementById("email").focus();
                  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        p_dialog.innerHTML="Please enter valid email ... ";         
               //document.form.name.select();
                return false;
            } 
        }
```

Comment: please format your code properly and add. Your code is like a paragraph

Comment: thnks i got ma mistake it isdocument.fom.email.select() i do copy from my another file ands forgot to change its work properly now

Comment: all the problems are solved but i try in 3 diff way but till it do not set focu()

Comment: 1) document.form.name.focus()   2)document.forms['form']['name'].focus(); 3)$('#name').focus(); no on woks with this dialog but works with alert

Comment: use this  document.getElementById("email").focus(); and before dialog box code and remove this line document.form.name.select();

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for validating Email ID. The below one is the standard one to use:

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator  ID="regEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="your_textboxid" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid Email ID" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                </td>

\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

Other wise put the above regex in your JS code, it should work fine.

See the edited JS code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validation() {
        var emailField = document.form.email.value;
        var reg =  \w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*;
        if (reg.test(emailField.value) == false) {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            p_dialog.innerHTML = "Please enter valid email ... ";
            document.form.name.select();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your provided code has more to it than what you've shown us, because it looks like you're trying to use jQuery but it's not being loaded in the example anywhere. (Edit: it wasn't in the example when I wrote this)

Having said that, in your Regex the + needs to go after the ] and before the )

```
var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+)\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
```